# Calling method with IEnumerable<T> sequence as argument, if that sequence is not empty

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumerator, yield-return

I have method `Foo`, which do some CPU intensive computations and returns `IEnumerable<T>` sequence. I need to check, if that sequence is empty. And if not, call method `Bar` with that sequence as argument.

I thought about three approaches...

- Check, if sequence is empty with `Any()`. This is ok, if sequence is really empty, which will be case most of the times. But it will have horrible performance, if sequence will contains some elements and `Foo` will need them compute again...
- Convert sequence to list, check if that list it empty... and pass it to `Bar`. This have also limitation. `Bar` will need only first `x` items, so `Foo` will be doing unnecessary work...
- Check, if sequence is empty without actually reset the sequence. This sounds like win-win, but I can't find any easy build-in way, how to do it. So I create this obscure workaround and wondering, whether this is really a best approach.

Condition

```
var source = Foo();

if (!IsEmpty(ref source))
    Bar(source);
```

with `IsEmpty` implemented as

```
bool IsEmpty<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        source = CreateIEnumerable(enumerator);
        return false;
    }

    return true;

    IEnumerable<T> CreateIEnumerable(IEnumerator<T> usedEnumerator)
    {
        yield return usedEnumerator.Current;

        while (usedEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return usedEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note, that calling `Bar` with empty sequence is not option...

**EDIT:**
After some consideration, best answer for my case is from **Olivier Jacot-Descombes** - avoid that scenario completely. Accepted solution answers this question - if it is really no other way.

Comment: You mean: `Foo` will need them compute again?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Ah, thanks, fixed :-)

Comment: It heavily depends on what `Foo` does exactly. `Any()` should only consume one element. If `Foo` uses `yield return` to compute the elements it will have to recompute only one element.

Comment: `Foo` need to initialize some resources, parse XML file and fill some HashSets, which will be used to filter (yield) returned data. This is not option unfortunately..

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You would like to "peek" the first value of the enumerable, but that's not part of the interface, so you start to enumerate it, and if you get at least one value, you create a combined enumerable with the first value concatenated with the yet-to-be-evaluated remainder of the enumeration.  The only problem I see is that you are not disposing the enumerator, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2008/03/15/yield-and-usings-your-dispose-may-not-be-called/

Comment: @dbc Yep, that is my question and thanks for letting me know about that disposable problem in my code...

Comment: This question belongs in code review. The code works.

Comment: If you can change your `Foo()` method to return [`IReadOnlyCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `IEnumerable<T>` then that would be quite efficient. An `IReadOnlyCollection` comprises an `IEnumerable<T>` and a `Count` (and nothing else).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I can't change `Foo` to return `IReadOnlyCollection`, because in most cases, not all items in that collection will be uses, so their computation will be useless...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You're assuming 1) that computing each element takes the same amount of time.  Often the first element is much more expensive than the rest 2) That the sequence computes the same values each time it's iterated 3) That iterating the sequence, even in part, doesn't cause side effects.  Those assumptions are violated by all sorts of sequences.

Comment: Why can you not implement `Bar` such that it simply behaves properly when passed an empty sequence?  This is almost always the preferable design.

Comment: @Servy This is addressed in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to call some function `Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)` if and only if the enumerable `source` contains at least one element, but you're running into two problems:

- There is no method `T Peek()` in [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) so you would need to actually begin to evaluate the enumerable to see if it's nonempty, but...
- You don't want to even partially double-evaluate the enumerable since setting up the enumerable might be expensive.

In that case your approach looks reasonable.  You do, however, have some issues with your imlementation:

1. You need to [dispose](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2008/03/15/yield-and-usings-your-dispose-may-not-be-called/) `enumerator` after using it.
2. As pointed out by [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582900/calling-method-with-ienumerablet-sequence-as-argument-if-that-sequence-is-not/53583238#comment94030199_53583238), if the `Bar()` method attempts to evaluate the `IEnumerable<T>` more than once (e.g. by calling `Any()` then `foreach (...)`) then the results will be undefined because `usedEnumerator` will have been exhausted by the first enumeration.

To resolve these issues, I'd suggest modifying your API a little and create an extension method `IfNonEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<IEnumerable<T>> func)` that calls a specified method only if the sequence is nonempty, as shown below:

```
public static partial class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IfNonEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<IEnumerable<T>> func)
    {
        if (source == null|| func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                return false;
            func(new UsedEnumerator<T>(enumerator));
            return true;
        }
    }

    class UsedEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        IEnumerator<T> usedEnumerator;

        public UsedEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> usedEnumerator)
        {
            if (usedEnumerator == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            this.usedEnumerator = usedEnumerator;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var localEnumerator = System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref usedEnumerator, null);
            if (localEnumerator == null)
                // An attempt has been made to enumerate usedEnumerator more than once; 
                // throw an exception since this is not allowed.
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            yield return localEnumerator.Current;
            while (localEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return localEnumerator.Current;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle with unit tests [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFCwkJ).

Comment: Unfortunately with or without dispose, the enumerable created from enumerator won't work if enumerated more than once by the consumer.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Well, that's true.  Maybe that should be protected against, let me think a bit...

Comment: @IvanStoev So.. if I call (in `Bar`) for example `.Any()` two times, the second call will fail?

Comment: @MatějPokorný - actually the behavior may be undefined since `usedEnumerator` will have been exhausted by the first enumeration.

Comment: @MatějPokorný Indeed. Because the enumerator will already be moved / disposed by the previous call.

Comment: @MatějPokorný - answer updated.  But overall the *After reading one of your comments...* approach by Olivier Jacot-Descombes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583118/3744182) seems less fragile.

Comment: @dbc thanks. I will keep that as accepted answer with some notes about that alternative in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether your algorithm in `Foo` allows to determine if the enumeration will be empty without doing the calculations. But if this is the case, return `null` if the sequence would be empty:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Foo()
{
    if (<check if sequence will be empty>) {
        return null;
    }
    return GetSequence();
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetSequence()
{
    ...
    yield return item;
    ...
}
```

Note that if a method uses `yield return`, it cannot use a simple `return` to return `null`. Therefore a second method is needed.

```
var sequence = Foo();
if (sequence != null) {
    Bar(sequence);
}
```

---

After reading one of your comments

> Foo need to initialize some resources, parse XML file and fill some HashSets, which will be used to filter (yield) returned data.

I suggest another approach. The time consuming part seems to be the initialization. To be able to separate it from the iteration, create a foo calculator class. Something like:

```
public class FooCalculator<T>
{
     private bool _isInitialized;
     private string _file;

     public FooCalculator(string file)
     {
         _file = file;
     }

     private EnsureInitialized()
     {
         if (_isInitialized) return;

         // Parse XML.
         // Fill some HashSets.

         _isInitialized = true;
     }

     public IEnumerable<T> Result
     {
         get {
             EnsureInitialized();
             ...
             yield return ...;
             ...
         }
     }
}
```

This ensures that the costly initialization stuff is executed only once. Now you can safely use `Any()`.

Other optimizations are conceivable. The `Result` property could remember the position of the first returned element, so that if it is called again, it could skip to it immediately.

Comment: That `EnsureInitialized` logic seems like best approach for my case, and I will probably go that way. Thanks. But I will check other answer as accepted, since this is not answering the original question...

Comment: Your "question" actually does not contain any question (ending with a question mark).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `Bar` then how about change it to `TryBar` that returns `false` when `IEnumerable<T>` was empty?

```
bool TryBar(IEnumerable<Foo> source)
{
  var count = 0;
  foreach (var x in source)
  {
    count++;
  }
  return count > 0;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you could always create your own `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper that caches values after they have been iterated once.

Comment: `Bar` can't be changed. It is external code and calling it means, that some error occured.

Comment: Creating a `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper that caches values when they are iterated is probably your best choice then.

Comment: Example this cached `IEnumerable<T>` implementation looks pretty solid https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl/blob/master/Rhino.Etl.Core/Enumerables/CachingEnumerable.cs (BSD-3 license)

Comment: It looks... I'm glad, that I'm not alone, who need something like this. Thanks for letting me know about that...

Comment: It seems that implementation expect `IEnumerable<T>` to be iterared completely when it's first iterated. So it won't work in your case because `.Any()` only iterates first element. Maybe you can get some pointers from that code how to write your own version that keeps wrapped iterator open until it's completely iterated/cached.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement for your `IsEmpty` would be to check if `source` is `ICollection<T>`, and if it is, check `.Count` (also, dispose the enumerator):

```
bool IsEmpty<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source is ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        return collection.Count == 0;
    }
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        source = CreateIEnumerable(enumerator);
        return false;
    }
    enumerator.Dispose();
    return true;
    IEnumerable<T> CreateIEnumerable(IEnumerator<T> usedEnumerator)
    {
        yield return usedEnumerator.Current;
        while (usedEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return usedEnumerator.Current;
        }
        usedEnumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will work for arrays and lists.

I would, however, rework `IsEmpty` to return:

```
IEnumerable<T> NotEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source is ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection.Count == 0)
        {
           return null;
        }
        return source;
    }
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        return CreateIEnumerable(enumerator);
    }
    enumerator.Dispose();
    return null;
    IEnumerable<T> CreateIEnumerable(IEnumerator<T> usedEnumerator)
    {
        yield return usedEnumerator.Current;
        while (usedEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return usedEnumerator.Current;
        }
        usedEnumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, you would check if it returned null.

Comment: The dispose in the outer method is referencing a variable name from the local function. I dont think that works

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is probably the best approach but, based on, and I quote:

> Convert sequence to list, check if that list it empty... and pass it to Bar. This have also limitation. Bar will need only first x items, so Foo will be doing unnecessary work...

Another take would be creating an `IEnumerable<T>` that partially caches the underlying enumeration. Something along the following lines:

```
interface IDisposableEnumerable<T>
    :IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
}

static class PartiallyCachedEnumerable
{
    public static IDisposableEnumerable<T> Create<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> source, 
        int cachedCount)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(
                nameof(source));

        if (cachedCount < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                nameof(cachedCount));

        return new partiallyCachedEnumerable<T>(
            source, cachedCount);
    }

    private class partiallyCachedEnumerable<T>
        : IDisposableEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
        private bool disposed;
        private readonly List<T> cache;
        private readonly bool hasMoreItems;

        public partiallyCachedEnumerable(
            IEnumerable<T> source, 
            int cachedCount)
        {
            Debug.Assert(source != null);
            Debug.Assert(cachedCount > 0);
            enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            cache = new List<T>(cachedCount);
            var count = 0;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext() && 
                   count < cachedCount)
            {
                cache.Add(enumerator.Current);
                count += 1;
            }

            hasMoreItems = !(count < cachedCount);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            enumerator.Dispose();
            disposed = true;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var t in cache)
                yield return t;

            if (disposed)
                yield break;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
                cache.Add(enumerator.Current)
            }

            Dispose();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            => GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```